# Ceating a SharePoint connection using service account in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

While creating a SharePoint connection , it always taking my email id as username .I am trying to connect with other account at login popup, but again it taking my email as username .

Can you please help how to add svc account having domain ct.chevrontexaco.net service account as username for API?

Answer (score 0):

We can make changes like below-

1. Go to particular Logic App and in the left hand side blades list,
   choose 'API Connections' under 'Development Tools' category.
   [image]
2. Check all the API connections associated with the logic app and
   choose the one that is related to SharePoint/office365.
3. Within the particular API Connection screen, in the left hand side
   blades list, choose 'Edit API Connection' under 'General' category.
   [image]
4. In the Edit API Connection Screen, Change the 'Display name' and click 'Authorize' and after
   authorization successfully done, click 'Save' below.
   [image]